# openpyxl - how can I style on character partial cell

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

Here is a cell like: x1, x2, x3.
My program can find the specific word x2, and I want to mark this word(x2) only.
How can I use openpyxl to mark the character only x2?

Answer (score 0):

Although excel supports formatting partial cells, openpyxl only supports formatting whole cells and not partial cells.

Comment: Thanks, btw, do you know any tool can do this?

Comment: Excel, Calc in LibreOffice etc. Do you accept your question is answered?